# How to monitor disk utilization in instances inside an auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to monitor the average `Disk Utilization` across all the EC2 instances inside an auto scaling group.

I know I can monitor `CPU Utilization` across all instances inside an auto scaling group because there's a CloudWatch metrics for that. However, I need CloudWatch Agent to monitor the `Disk Utilization`. Is there a good way to monitor this? Or do I need to implement my own automation using Lambda?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor"? Are you wanting to trigger Alarms, or draw graphs, or something else?

Comment: I want to trigger alarms when the disk utilization reaches certain level

Comment: You'd need to create separate alarms for each EC2 instance. Frankly, it might be easier to run a background script on each instance that checks disk utilization every _x_ minutes and sends a message to an Amazon SNS Topic if it falls below a desired level.

Answer (score 1):

CPU Utilization is managed by the Operating System, which runs 'inside' the EC2 instance. **AWS has no access to your Operating System** and, therefore, no knowledge of your disk utilization. For the same reason, an AWS Lambda function would not be able to access this information either.

Instead, [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html). The CloudWatch is probably already installed on the instance and can be configured to [collect metrics such as](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html):

- disk_total
- disk_used
- disk_used_percent
- mem_available
- mem_used

Comment: I know that I need to use CloudWatch Agent to get the disk utilization metrics. What I want to know is how to get the metrics for **all EC2 instances inside an auto scaling group**. So that I can monitor the instances in the CloudWatch Alarm

Comment: [Monitor CloudWatch metrics for your Auto Scaling groups and instances - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-cloudwatch-monitoring.html) describes how metrics are collected and computed for an Auto Scaling group (eg Average 'CPU Utilization'), but I couldn't see a mention of including Custom Metrics in the calculation (and Desk Utilization is a Custom Metric). Plus, you probably want per-instance disk utilization rather than an average of all systems.